# keeping/removing a reduntant cout in my cpp program changes my answer

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
     int t;
     cin >> t;
     while(t-->0){
          int n;
          int a[n];
          int max=0;
          cin >> n;
          for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
               cin >> a[i];
          }
          max=a[0]+a[1]+a[2];
          for(int i=3; i<n; i++){
               if((a[i]+a[i-1]+a[i-2])>max){
                    max=a[i]+a[i-1]+a[i-2];
               }
          }
        //   cout << "max = " << max << endl;
          if((a[n-1]+a[n-2]+a[0])>max)
          {
               max=(a[n-1]+a[n-2]+a[0]);
          }
          if((a[n-1]+a[1]+a[0])>max)
          {
               max=(a[n-1]+a[1]+a[0]);
          }
          cout << max <<endl;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

This is a simple cpp program for this problem : https://www.codechef.com/COG2020/problems/COG2002#.
When I am adding a print statement, which is reduntant then it gives correct answer. And when I remove it, then I get a wrong answer. 
My input is : 
2
3
1 2 2
3 
1 2 2

Please tell what could be the possible reasons. I have searched google for any explanations but couldn't find any :(

Comment: What answer do you get?

Comment: `int a[n];` is nonsense. ask yourself what is `n` at that time (assuming you're using a non-standard extension for VLAs, which C++ doesn't support for the current standard). Read `n`, then use a `std::vector<int> a(n);` after validating `n` is reasonable.

Comment: @WhozCraig, assign value to n i.e cin>>n before int a[n] then everything works fine

Comment: @dheerajVadlani *"then everything works fine"* not if your toolchain doesn't support VLAs. DO what I said earlier and it will work on *all* implementations; no need to rely on non-standard extensions.

Comment: Most bad C++ programs (like yours) exhibit what's called *undefined behaviour*. This means that the C++ standard does not define any behaviour for your program. A program with undefined behaviour can crash, it can run but produce the wrong results or it can work as you were expecting. All of these are possible. Also, when you have undefined behaviour, seemingly trival changes can make the difference between one outcome and another. This is what you are seeing.

Comment: @dheerajVadlani, It worked. @ john and @ WhozCraig, thanks for ur explanation